# Missing libyaml in Ruby (on rails) OCRA Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ocra

I've developed a very simple rails application (which plots some diagrams based on data in the database).

Now, my customer want to use this rails application online as well as offline.

So I've used OCRA to create an .exe-File out of it (which works good!).
If I run my .exe-File on the development-Machine, everytihing works as expected. A rails server will be booted up and I'm able to use the application by opening up 127.0.0.1:3000.

However, If I use the same .exe-File on a different machine, there's an error saying that I need to install psych / libyaml before rails to use rails properly.

I've build my OCRA-Application with this command:

```
ocra example_sqlite_chartjs\bin\rails example_sqlite_chartjs --add-all-core --gemfile example_sqlite_chartjs\Gemfile --no-dep-run --gem-full --chdir-first --output example_sqlite_chartjs.exe -- server
```

I've used the railsinstaller (for windows) from http://railsinstaller.org/en so I think, that everything should be included here.

This guy seems to have a similar issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ruby-ocra/libyaml/ruby-ocra/D5StGPzZsbE/YLOEkAKM0-oJ

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Philipp

Answer (score 3):

So I've found a solution for this one. All I had to do is to add the dependent .dlls which can be found in the bin-Directory of the ruby installation.

I've used this command to do so:

```
ocra example_sqlite_chartjs\bin\rails example_sqlite_chartjs --add-all-core --gemfile example_sqlite_chartjs\Gemfile --no-dep-run --gem-full --dll libeay32.dll --dll libffi-6.dll --dll libgdbm_compat-3.dll --dll libgdbm-3.dll --dll libiconv-2.dll --dll libyaml-0-2.dll --dll msvcrt-ruby191.dll --dll pdcurses.dll --dll sqlite3.dll --dll ssleay32.dll --dll tcl85.dll --dll tclpip85.dll --dll tk85.dll --dll zlib1.dll --chdir-first --output example_sqlite_chartjs.exe -- server
```

Hope this helps anyone else!